# change the order of the digits of a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology

What is prime numbers called, that if you arbitrary change the order of its digits, you will only get another prime number. 
For example 79 (79 is prime number as well 97) or 199 (199, 919, 991 is prime numbers)

Comment: I don't think there is a standard name for this. Have in mind that this property is base-dependant. For exaple, $79$ in Hexadecimal is $0x65$ and $0x56$ in Hex is not a prime.

Comment: Not satisfied with the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

This type of primes is called [Permutable prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutable_prime), and the sequence in OEIS is [A004359](http://oeis.org/A003459), where it is called an “absolute prime”.  There is also another type of primes called *Emirp* which includes primes which still primes when the digits are reversed.